# Using rawSystem With cmd.exe; Arg After "/c" has Prepended Quotation Mark, Causing Error

Tags: windows, haskell, cmd

In Haskell, running `rawSystem "cmd.exe" ["/c", "dir"]` produces cmd's unrecognized command message as displayed below:

```
Prelude System.Cmd> rawSystem "cmd.exe" ["/c", "dir"]
'"dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ExitFailure 1
```

The problem, as indicated in the error message, is that my second argument is prepended with a quotation mark (`"`). The same goes for `["/c", ""]` as arguments; it says `'"' not recognized`.

I'm guessing this is more of cmd's fault, than Haskell's, however I need a Haskell solution to deal with this, so:

Why does this happen?

And more importantly, what can I do to avoid this issue?

Comment: Just noticed `system` in the same module as `rawSystem`. Turns out you can just simply do: `system "dir"`.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Haskell to me.  I had a peek at the source code, and how rawSystem is handled appears to depend on how your particular instance of Haskell was compiled, so it may be implementation-specific.  Something like `rawSystem "cmd.exe" ["/c dir"]` might be more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

CMD needs the "/C dir" in one parameter

cmd.exe "/c dir"

if you use

```
cmd.exe "/c" "dir"
```

it would be interpreted as

```
/c" "dir
```

where "dir is no valid command

Comment: -1.  `cmd "/c dir"` isn't valid, although `cmd "/c" dir` is.  Really the bottom line is that Haskell shouldn't be inserting quotation marks *at all*.